# architecture and tools for a remote control application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, remote-control

I'm working on the design of a remote control application.  From my iPhone or a web browser, I'll send a few commands.  Soon my home computer will perform the commands and send back results.  I know there are remote desktop apps, but I want something programmable, something simpler, and something that I wrote.

My current direction is to use Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) as the message bus.  The iPhone places some messages in a queue.  My local Java/JRuby program notices the messages on the queue, performs the work and sends back status via a different queue.

This will be a very low-volume application.  At $1.00 for a million requests (plus a handful of data transfer charges), Amazon SQS looks a lot more affordable than having my own server of any type.  And super reliable, that's important for me too.

Are there better/standard toolkits or architectures for this kind of remote control?  Cost is not a big issue, but I prefer the tons I learn by doing it myself.

I'm moderately concerned about security, but doubt it will be a problem.  The list of commands recognized will be very short, and only recognized in specific contexts.  No "erase hard drive" stuff.

*update*: I'll probably distribute these programs to some other people who want the same function, but who don't have Amazon SQS accounts.  For now, they'll use anonymous access to my queues, with random 80-character queue names.

Comment: What would this do that ssh (secure shell) wouldn't do?

Comment: It lets him keep his home machine behind a firewall, since it's talking to the queues directly, rather than listening to an open port on the internet.

Comment: Yup, I don't have control over my home IP address.  Plus I'd like a near-zero config for the other users, with no knowledge of their setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think it's a clever approach -- and as you said, the costs for your little traffic aren't even worth mentioning.

As I mentioned in the comment, it's a good way to leave your home machine behind your firewall and not have an open port on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using OnlineMQ.com as a start; they have a free package.

Comment: Look interesting.  I can't tell from the site what the pros and cons are.  Do you have any experience to share?